# how to populate text field based on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I have a dropdown which contains ID from database, so when I select one ID from the list based on the ID the text field must be populated.

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Equipment ID:<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select name="equipmentid" id="input18" class="select2-select-00 col-md-12  form-control input-width-xlarge form-control required"   multiple size="5">
                                <?php
                                $data = DB::table('tbl_addequipment')->where('last_month', '=', $data2)->get();

                                foreach ($data as $row2) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option  value="<?php echo "EQ".$row2->equipment_tag ?>"><?php echo "EQ".$row2->equipment_tag ?></option>

                                                <?php } ?>
                                                </select>
                                        </div>
```

and my text field

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Maintenance Type:<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10" >
                                        <input class="form-control input-width-xlarge form-control required" style="display: block; margin-top: 6px;" type="text" name="maintenancetype" id="maintenancetype" > 

                                    </div>
```

I have tried this code but doesn't work and I don't get error.

```
<?php


                                $data3 = $row2->equipment_tag ;
                                $data4 = DB::table('tbl_maintenancerecord')->where('equipment_tag', '=', $data3)->get(); 

                                ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
                                    $('select[name="equipmentid"]').change(function()
                                    {
                                         $('#maintenancetype').val($('select[name="equipmentid"] option:selected').data('mstatus'));
                                    }
                                    );
                                    </script>
```

Comment: Near  foreach ($data as $row2) {
  the php stops

Comment: @EnriqueQuero because from there html starts and i have ended foreach after that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   $data4 = DB::table('tbl_maintenancerecord')->where('equipment_tag', '=', $data3)->select('mstatus')->get()->first();
       echo '<div class="tbl_maintenancerecord" data-tag="'.$data3.'" data-val="'.$data4.'"></div>';


        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
         $('select[name="equipmentid"]').change(function()
             {
                 var d = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                 $('#maintenancetype').val($('body').find('div[data-tag="'+d+'"]').attr('data-val'));
             });
        }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: i tried that but it prints the same value that i select from drop down but i want the value from the maintenance record table.

Comment: you need ajax for that

Comment: can you help me with that, I'm beginner in Ajax.

Comment: you are a beginner in web development not only ajax you need to get some courses and learn proper web development

Comment: i tried that but nothing appears in the textfield and yeah I'm learning now.

Comment: what does the console, erros?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in 53d7f6b26fd9b4eecf8579ad84ed3c on line 912

Comment: and i fixed it by adding semicolon

Comment: what filed/fields you want in your text box form tbl_maintenancerecord?

Comment: i have only two records.

Comment: i need only one "mstatus"

Comment: not working, empty text field and no error in console.

Comment: var_dump $data and $data4 and post it here

Comment: sorry i didn't add "first()" in the code and now I'm getting an error with that.

Comment: FatalErrorException in ef53d7f6b26fd9b4eecf8579ad84ed3c line 909:
Call to a member function first() on array

Comment: how to var_dump $data ?

Comment: realy REALY?? var_dump($data);

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#213 (13) { ["equipment_tag"]=> string(1) "1" ["equipment_type"]=> string(15) "Cutting Machine" ["equipment_name"]=> string(2) "ab" ["brand"]=> string(3) "abc" ["date_added"]=> string(10) "2015-12-09" ["frequency"]=> string(7) "1 month" ["next_review"]=> string(10) "2016-01-09" ["status"]=> string(1) "3" ["last_review"]=> string(10) "2015-12-01" ["last_month"]=> int(12) ["token"]=> string(0) "" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#214 (13) { ["equipment_tag"]=> string(1) "2" ["equipment_type"]=> string(15) "welding machine" ["equipment_name"]=> string(4) "abcc" ["brand"]=> string(5) "bosch" ["date_added"]=> string(10) "2015-12-14" ["frequency"]=> string(7) "1 month" ["next_review"]=> string(10) "2016-01-14" ["status"]=> string(1) "2" ["last_review"]=> string(10) "2015-12-14" ["last_month"]=> int(12) ["token"]=> string(0) "" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } } array(0) { }

Comment: i get this in the form

Comment: in data 4 array(0) { }

Comment: that means you have no records in tbl_maintenancerecord linked with tbl_addequipment

Comment: there was one record and now i added 4 more and ran the dump but it gives ''array to string conversion error" in echo statement.

Comment: get the first using `first()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you are missing the data-attribute "mstatus" on the selected option field. Where do you set this? Try the following instead after your change function:

```
 $('#maintenancetype').val($('#equipmentid').find(":selected").text());
```

Comment: i get "mstatus" from tbl_maintenancerecord table.